# Using onCreate with Firebase Cloud Functions in Nested collection

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am looking to create a Firebase Cloud Function that gets called every time a document gets created. Using their tutorial I have the following code in:

```
exports.sendConfirmationEmail = functions.firestore.document('collection1/{resId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {
      // my method
    });
```

now this method gets called every time a document gets added to collection1. But I have a database structure that looks like the following:

| businesses

| => business document

| => | reservations

Not sure if that makes any sense but essentially there is a business collection where each business document contains a reservations subcollection. I need to write a function that gets executed every time a document gets added to the reservations collection in each business, but still be able to access the business document somehow. How can I accomplish this? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your function definition will look like this:

```
exports.yourFunctionName =
functions.firestore.document('businesses/{businessId}/reservations/{reservationId}')
.onCreate((snap, context) => {
    // your code goes here
});
```

Comment: would `snap.data()` correspond to the reservation? Also how could I access the business, because the point is to be able to access both the reservation and the business document. Thanks for your quick reply!

Comment: It will refer to the document that triggered the function.  If you need another document, you will have to query it separately.

Comment: Ok, so how can I get the `businessId` value so I can query it?

Comment: Please limit yourself to a single question per post on Stack Overflow.  I think a lot of your questions are going to be covered by the documentation.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events

Comment: Thanks I found the code snippet I was looking for. Do you mind if I edit your answer to include it or would you want me to create a new answer?

Answer (score 4):

For any one else, looking here is what this would look like when trying to retrieve both the business and the reservation:

```
exports.getReservationFromBusiness = functions.firestore.document('businesses/{bisId}/reservations/{resId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {
      const businessId = context.params.bisId;
      const reservation = snap.data();
    });
```

This code is from the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) and Github [page](https://github.com/firebase/snippets-node/blob/9eca5ffa507a7760f38a2547d731916ba75f8e5c/firestore/extend-with-functions/functions/index.js#L150-L160).